# Getting wrong answer when int32 behave wierd, how do I solve it? C#

Tags: c#, int32

Im trying to get the result with this code. It is suppose to work with whatever numer/numbers I choose, but it does only work with a "0" in the end. (val1, is the textbox I am writing the number/numbers in) and (yarncombobox, ft3.garnlangd1 is where I get the value that is needed in the calculation). I guess Int32 might be wrong...what should I use instead?

Also, When removing all numbers I get error message "System.FormatException: 'Indatasträngen hade ett felaktigt format.'"

```
private void YarnWeightTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

            Int32 val1 = Convert.ToInt32(YarnWeightTextbox.Text);
        Class2 ft3 = YarnComboBox.SelectedItem as Class2;
        {
            YarnLengthTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString((val1 / 50) * ft3.garnlangd1);
```

Edit: I did get it somewhat to work, it does give right value with float. But the same problem. When deleting all numbers in the same box the app crashes.

```
            float val1 = Convert.ToSingle(YarnWeightTextbox.Text);
        Class2 ft3 = YarnComboBox.SelectedItem as Class2;
        float val2 = val1 / 50 * ft3.garnlangd1;
        {
            YarnLengthTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString(val2);
```

Comment: The `FormatException` is because the `TextChanged` event fires every time you change the text including when you have removed all of the text. `Convert.ToInt32` then tries to convert an empty string to an integer and then throws the exception.

When you say it doesn't work for anything other than 0, what do you mean? What happens? Is an exception thrown? Or just the wrong output in textbox?

Comment: With int32, If i write "50" its "170", as it should be, but when I change it to "55" its still "170". If i write "555" I get "1700"But...I have tried with "float val1 = Convert.ToSingle(YarnWeightTextbox.Text);", that did accouly do the right calculation. But its the same. When I delete everything i get that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shane Haw mentioned in the comments, you're getting the `FormatException` because the `TextChanged` event fires **any time the text changes**.

If the value in `YarnWeightTextBox.Text` is `"5"`, and you delete the `"5"` then the `TextChanged` event fires. Which means that you are passing an empty string `""` to `Convert.ToSingle`. An empty string does not convert to a `float` and so you get the `FormatException`. You will get the same thing if you put anything other than a digit in that `TextBox` as well.

A better option would be to check if the value in `YarnWeightTextBox.Text` parses to a `float` instead of using `Convert.ToFloat`.

```csharp
private void YarnWeightTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   float val1 = 0.0F;
   if (!float.TryParse(YarnWeightTextBox.Text, out val1))
   {
      // The value in YarnWeightTextBox.Text does not parse to a float. You could 
      // do something here to indicate to the user that they did not provide a correct
      // value, or just return.
      return;
   }
   // Calculate the yarn length and put it in the YarnLengthTextBox.Text like you're doing now.
}
```

Alternatively, if this is `Windows Forms`, you might have a look at the [`NumericUpDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown) control which will prevent users for entering invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

```
private void YarnWeightTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Check for the empty string. If it is empty then just return
        string weight = YarnWeightTextbox.Text;
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(weight))
        {
            return;
        }

        //Otherwise convert to integer or to a float as you have
        Int32 val1 = Convert.ToInt32(YarnWeightTextbox.Text);

        Class2 ft3 = YarnComboBox.SelectedItem as Class2;
        //When casting using the `as` operator. I make a point of checking for null just
        //in case for some reason it isn't an instance of the class I expect.
        if(ft3 != null)
        {
            //Finally change the 50 to 50.0. This tells the compiler to divide using a float
            //rather than an integer. Dividing 2 integers results in the truncation of the fractional part
            YarnLengthTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString((val1 / 50.0) * ft3.garnlangd1);
        }
}
```

The most important parts are:

1. Check for empty string
2. Divide using float division rather than integer division as integer division will remove the fractional part of the result, which may account for some of the strange results that you are seeing.

Comment: Oh, I do understand how it works now (great explanation). I did try to write, but I get next error, "return" invalid pression term. I did also try (); and ; and : same after return with same error..

Answer (score 0):

```
private void YarnWeightTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (float.TryParse(textBox.Text, out var yarnWeight) && YarnComboBox.SelectedItem is Class2 class2)
        {
            var yarnLength = (yarnWeight / 50.0) * class2.garnlangd1;

            YarnLengthTextbox.Text = yarnLength.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            YarnLengthTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need additional logic to check the value of YarnComboBox.SelectedItem before attempting to use its value.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add information to your answer, instead of commenting it.

Comment: I did "YarnComboBox.SelectedItem" has a string in "Class2" that is named "garnlangd1" where I put the value I need. :)